# Calling a method with a java.lang.Class in Jython

Tags: java, class, jython

I'm trying to use SimpleLog from Jython but I can't find any way of using its constructors because one of the arguments is always a java.lang.Class.

logger = SimpleLogger(**name**) <--doesn't work
logger = SimpleLogger(self)     <--doesn't work
logger = SimpleLogger(SimpleLogger.class)     <--doesn't work

The problem right now is with SimpleLog, but I bet many other libraries have this approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the type itself, it maps to the class in Java:

```
logger = SimpleLogger (SimpleLogger)

from com.foo import DaClass
logger = SimpleLogger (DaClass)
```

etc.

Comment: ugh! I didn't try that! Thank you!